# How Do I Call An Inherited JavaScript Constructor With Parameters?

Tags: javascript, parameters, constructor

Greetings,

After reading the following article I have a question: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

In the inheritance example, the Person constructor doesn't take any parameters. How would this same example look if I were to add one and call it from the Student constructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, a way that you can re-use the logic of the `Person` constructor is invoking it with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), for example:

```
function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
}

function Student(gender) {
  Person.apply(this, arguments);
}
Student.prototype = new Person(); // make Student inherit from a Person object
Student.prototype.constructor = Student; // fix constructor property

var foo = new Student('male');
foo.gender;             // "male"
foo instanceof Student; // true
foo instanceof Person;  // true
```

If you want to prevent the execution of the `Person` constructor when is called without arguments (like in the line: `Student.prototype = new Person();`), you can detect it, e.g.:

```
function Person(gender) {
  if (arguments.length == 0) return; // don't do anything
  this.gender = gender;
}
```

Comment: @CMS For the second portion `if (arguments.length == 0) return;`, is there a way to handle constructors where the arguments are NOT required? In that situation, am I forced to call the constructor?

Comment: I've tried a lot of different methods (`Object.create`, `Person.prototype`, temp functions...) but all of them fail or have bugs (undefined properties, obscured ones, etc.). Thanks for this answer, finally one that really works!

Answer (score 11):

Accepted answer seems to be incorrect. Based on what [Mozilla says about OO JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript), correct way to do it is:

```
var Person = function(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
};

function Student(firstName, subject) {
  // Call the parent constructor, making sure (using Function#call)
  // that "this" is set correctly during the call
  Person.call(this, firstName);

  // Initialize our Student-specific properties
  this.subject = subject;
};

// Create a Student.prototype object that inherits from Person.prototype.
// Note: A common error here is to use "new Person()" to create the
// Student.prototype. That's incorrect for several reasons, not least 
// that we don't have anything to give Person for the "firstName" 
// argument. The correct place to call Person is above, where we call 
// it from Student.
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // See note below

// Set the "constructor" property to refer to Student
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

// Example usage:
var student1 = new Student("Janet", "Applied Physics");
```

As you can clearly see, Mozilla specifies that it is a common error to use "new Person()" to create the Student.prototype. Hence accepted answer is misleading.

I have actually tested this in my ongoing project and Mozilla's way is correct, while above answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the Person Class
function Person(name) {
    this.personname = name;
}

Person.prototype.walk = function(){};
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert (this.personname );
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

---

**The full code:**

```
<script>
// define the Person Class
function Person(name) {
    this.personname = name;
}

Person.prototype.walk = function(){};
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert (this.personname );
};

// define the Student class
function Student() {}

// inherit Person
Student.prototype = new Person("test");

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

// replace the sayHello method
Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert('hi, I am a student and my name is \'' + this.personname + '\'' );
}

// add sayGoodBye method
Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function(){
  alert('goodBye');
}

var student1 = new Student();
student1.sayHello();
student1.sayGoodBye();
</script>
```

Comment: I think this works fine if you always want "test" as the person name, but this is not what I mean when I ask to call it from the Student constructor.

Answer (score 0):

By all other comments I created an example which works for me. Since I did not use prototype explicitly I hope I am not missing an important point.

```
// variable for tracking instantiations and checking the uniqueness of the objects
var instances = 0;

var Generic = function() {
    this.instanceId = ++instances;
    this.toString = function() {return 'Generic [iid='+ this.instanceId +']'};
    console.log('constructor-invoke: Generic ('+ this.instanceId +')');
};

var SpecificName = function(inName) {
    Generic.call(this);
    this.getName = function() { return inName; };       
    var superToString = this.toString.bind(this); // binds the inner function 'this' to this SpecificName instance
    this.toString = function() {
        return 'SpecificName [iid='+ this.instanceId +', name='+ this.getName() +', super.toString='+ superToString() +']'
    }
    console.log('constructor-invoke: SpecificName ('+ this.instanceId +')');
};

var SpecificNames = function(inFirstName, inLastName) {
    SpecificName.call(this, inLastName +', '+ inFirstName );
    var superToString = this.toString.bind(this);
    this.toString = function() {
        return 'SpecificNames [iid='+ this.instanceId +', name='+ this.getName() +', super.toString='+ superToString() +']'
    }
    console.log('constructor-invoke: SpecificNames ('+ this.instanceId +')');
};

var g = new Generic(); 
var sn = new SpecificName('Run Forest Run');
var sns = new SpecificNames('Forest','Gump');

console.log('g:   '+ g.toString());
console.log('sn:  '+ sn.toString());
console.log('sns: '+ sns.toString());
```

leads to this output:

```
constructor-invoke: Generic (1)
constructor-invoke: Generic (2)
constructor-invoke: SpecificName (2)
constructor-invoke: Generic (3)
constructor-invoke: SpecificName (3)
constructor-invoke: SpecificNames (3)
g:   Generic [iid=1]
sn:  SpecificName [iid=2, name=Run Forest Run, super.toString=Generic [iid=2]]
sns: SpecificNames [iid=3, name=Gump, Forest, super.toString=SpecificName [iid=3, name=Gump, Forest, super.toString=Generic [iid=3]]]
```