# JavaScript - constructor parameters and prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript

I am using this type of code for inheritance. The problem is i am getting error when set up `prototype` of `B`, because `new A()` tries to access `params.param` and `params` is `undefined` when setting up `B.prototype`. How to deal with it? Or i should use another style for simulating inheritance in js?

```
function A(params) {
  this.param = params.param; // this will throw error when set up B prototype
}

function B(params) {
  A.call(this, params); // this is ok
}

B.prototype = new A(); // this is bad, A need some parameters
```

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533473/javascript-inheritance-when-constructor-has-arguments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785955/inherit-parent-constructor-arguments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601932/how-do-i-call-an-inherited-javascript-constructor-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way and won't get the problem.

```
var EmptyFunc = function() {};
EmptyFunc.prototype = A.prototype;

B.prototype = new EmptyFunc;
```